# homotopy and arrival space of an homotopic function

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have an exercise to solve where the goal is to show that a space $X$ is homotopic equivalent to a point if and only if, $\forall f:X\to Y$ is nullhomotopic for any given $Y$.
I think that the best way to prove it is using the proposition that says

> $X$ is homotopic equivalent to a point if and only if the identity function is homotopic to the constant function

that way I can show that
$$f\simeq \operatorname{id}_X\simeq \operatorname{const}_X$$
So now I'm stuck because I can't understand what does the existance of an homotopy implies for the space involved and i've even created a counterexample.
Let's say that $X=D^2$, where $D^2$ is the unit disk, and $Y=S^0$. Now let's use the function $g:D^2\to S^0$ where
$$g(x,y)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lc}+1&if\;x>1\\-1&\;otherwise\end{array}\right.$$
This function goes from a contractible space to another space and it's not homotpic to the identity.
Where I'm making mistakes?

Comment: Is your function continuous?

Comment: The exercise says "for any given map from your space X to any space Y" so i think not.

Comment: Continuity is required in topology.

Comment: It has to be a continuous map. Some authors don't mention it, because they think it is simply obvious that the only interesting maps in topology are continuous, so they always assume continuity without mentioning. I don't think it's a good enough excuse, but it is what it is.

Comment: Well that's explains a lot.
I'll post the solution once i'll find it

Comment: There is often a blanket statement early on that “map” means continuous function.